# Fixed dropdown menu scrollable

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have a fixed dropdown menu that needs to be able to scroll if its height is larger than the viewport. I tried adding overflow: scroll and overflow: auto to the menu, but neither seemed to work. Where am I going wrong?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L7wxsqan/

CSS for menu:

```
#nav ul li:hover>ul {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
a.blocklink {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: inherit;
 display: block;
}

#nav {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: white;
}

#projects {
 display: inline-block;
}

#nav ul {
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #000000;
 list-style-type: none;
 text-align: center;
 margin: auto;
 padding-top: 6px;
 padding-right: 0px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-left: 0px;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

#nav ul ul {
 width: calc(100% - 20px);
 list-style-type: none;
 font-weight: normal;
 display: none;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

#nav ul li {
  position: relative;
}

#nav ul li:hover>ul {
 display: block;
 position: fixed;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding-top: 10px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

#one {
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 color: #000000;
 background-color: white;
}

#one:active {
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
}

#one:hover {
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
}

@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
 #nav ul ul {
  width: 20%;
 }   
}
```

```html
        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
               <li id="projects">
                  Projects
                  <ul>
                     <a href="/one" class="blocklink">
                        <li id="one">One</li>
                     </a>    
                     <a href="/one" class="blocklink">
                        <li id="one">One</li>
                     </a> 
                     <a href="/one" class="blocklink">
                        <li id="one">One</li>
                     </a> 
                     <a href="/one" class="blocklink">
                        <li id="one">One</li>
                     </a>   
                     <a href="/one" class="blocklink">
                        <li id="one">One</li>
                     </a>    
                     <a href="/one" class="blocklink">
                        <li id="one">One</li>
                     </a> 
                     <a href="/one" class="blocklink">
                        <li id="one">One</li>
                     </a> 
                     <a href="/one" class="blocklink">
                        <li id="one">One</li>
                     </a>  
                     <a href="/one" class="blocklink">
                        <li id="one">One</li>
                     </a>    
                     <a href="/one" class="blocklink">
                        <li id="one">One</li>
                     </a> 
                     <a href="/one" class="blocklink">
                        <li id="one">One</li>
                     </a> 
                     <a href="/one" class="blocklink">
                        <li id="one">One</li>
                     </a>   
                     <a href="/one" class="blocklink">
                        <li id="one">One</li>
                     </a>    
                     <a href="/one" class="blocklink">
                        <li id="one">One</li>
                     </a> 
                     <a href="/one" class="blocklink">
                        <li id="one">One</li>
                     </a> 
                     <a href="/one" class="blocklink">
                        <li id="one">One</li>
                     </a>                          
                  </ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
```

All you need to do is adding this code (make the parent position relative):

```
#nav ul li {
  position: relative;
}
```

and add `max-height: 100%;` in the second ul.

Comment: Perfection. Have a great day! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set `#nav ul ul` a height 100% or something else